# Wordpres: Installation failed: Download failed. No working transports found

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wamp, wampserver

I'm using windows 7, Wamp, PHP version 7.4.16, MySQL Version 4.9.7, and Apache 2.4.23.
I'm unable to download theme and plugins on WordPress. I have searched a lot on this issue and tried the Following solutions but all in vain.

Uncommented the php_curl and php-openssl.
Copied the two/ three files from PHP to apache bin

Last but not least I'm using the latest version of WordPress. Any quick help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had that problem since for ever. Never managed to fix it, the only way i'm doing it right now is by manually downloading WP latest version then overwriting existing file. The only real thing you want to save on a local environment is the `wp-content` folder.

Comment: ___Copied the two/ three files from PHP to apache bin___ Thats NEVER NECESSARY. So that coudl be what has shot you in the foot

Comment: windows 7 might be your other probelm

Comment: _MySQL Version 4.9.7_ Really??

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well I keep on undo the changes if it does not work, WampServer 3.0.6

Comment: @amarinediary Changing the path from the system variable worked for me. DO try!

Comment: Changing what path, please explain, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to download a theme and found a solution here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292175/installation-failed-download-failed-no-working-transports-found?newreg=571f25138e3a44d5abfc6fae52765759

Basically, you have to edit your php.ini to enable the php-openssl.dll extension and that's all!